# Typing notification in node.js using KeyUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am using Node.js and making a chat application.

Assume user A is chatting with user B. In all chat applications whenever each user starts typing, a notifier appears that says " user X is Typing...".

I have a "typing ..." functionality like it. using this method:

```
$(document).on('keyup','form.chat input:text', function(e){
    var $id = $(this).attr('id'); // text id is the user id we are chating with.
    if ( $(this).val().trim().length > 0 )
        socket.emit("writingOn", $id );
    if ( $(this).val().trim().length === 0 )
        socket.emit("writingOff", $id );
});
```

It is working well. But the question is:
**Is this a good method? Because foreach keyUp client sends a req to Server**

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're really using a socket, not a full request will be sent - the connection is already opened and it sends only a tiny message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a good method?

For sending every keystroke in a live-edit application, yes. For providing a "is typing" feature, no.

You only need to send a message when the user starts typing, and a message when he hasn't typed for some predetermined period of time. Use a timeout for that which is reset on every following keystroke. In your case, you will need a collection of timeouts for each field he could be typing in.

```
var timeouts = {},
    time = 2000;
$(document).on('keyup','form.chat input:text', function(e){
    var id = this.id/*,
        isEmpty = /^\s*$/.test(this.value) */;
    if (id in timeouts) // if something is scheduled
        clearTimeout(timeouts[id]); // remove it
    else /* if (!isEmpty) */ // else this is the first stroke
        socket.emit("writingOn", id);
    // schedule sending the off-message, which will be canceled when another
    // keystroke happens
    timeouts[id] = setTimeout(function() {
        socket.emit("writingOff", id);
        delete timeouts[id];
    }, /* isEmpty ? 0 : */ time);
});
```

Comment: Same idea as I was having, but I like your implementation better :)

Comment: Thank you, But I really can not understand what this code does. Does this code check every 2 seconds whether a user is typing or not? I mean every 2 seconds it sends a message to Server ?

Comment: No, every time the user hits a key the message-sending is scheduled for 2s from now. If in that period another key event is triggered, the sending is unscheduled and replaced by another one again lasting for 2s.